# How do I do a Go/Golang type assertion for "type MyString string"?

Tags: go

If I want to know whether a variable is of type string, I can do a type assertion:

```
S, OK:= value.(string)
```

If value is of type string, then OKis true, and S is the original value.

But this type assertion doesn't work for custom string types; for example:

```
type MyString string
```

For a variable of this type, the above type assertion returns false for OK.

How can I determine if a variable is of type string, or of an equivalent type, without a separate assertion for each such equivalent type?

Comment: You cannot. As you know you can test for "beeing string" like `value.(string)` or you can test for "being MyString` with `value.(MyString)`, but you cannot for both. Or you use a type switch. Work through the Tour of Go once more, especially the chapter about type switches: https://tour.golang.org/methods/16 and ff.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot perform a type assertion or a type switch to a string, as the **exact type** does not match. The closest you can get is to use the [`reflect`](https://godoc.org/reflect) package and check the value's [`Kind`](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.Kind):

```
var S string
ref := reflect.ValueOf(value)
if ref.Kind() == reflect.String {
    S = ref.String()
}
```

Comment: In place of the last line ("S = ref.String()"), could I simply say "S = value"?

Comment: @MartinDelVecchio: No, because the type of `S` is not the same as the type of `value`.

Comment: OK.  My goal here is to avoid calling value.String() or its equivalent, because it's already a string.  How can I convert a variable of type MyString to a variable of type string?  Does "string (value)" do it?

Comment: @TimCooper Thanks for your answer. Can you explain why type switch isn't accurate wihile checking the exact type ?

Comment: @nexus66: [Type assertions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) "x.(T) asserts that the dynamic type of x is **identical** to the type T"

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Why you use an assertion, it's for interfaces. Try conversion like:

```
type MyString string

var s MyString = "test"
var t string

t = string(s)
```

Comment: It is an interface; I have a function that takes an arbitrary value (the argument value is of type interface{}), and I want to return a string.  For actual string variables, and for variables of equivalent types (e.g., MyString), I want to return the original value as efficiently as possible.  For others (int, struct, etc.), I will have to use a String() method or fmt.Sprintf(), etc.

Comment: I see, in this case only reflection can solve the problem